# Celery write task traceback to log

Tags: logging, celery

Is there a way to output a scheduled task's traceback to the console or to a log file?

There are many answers concerning simple tasks but nothing seems to work.

Thanks!

Comment: I am confused - scheduled tasks ARE regular tasks. The only difference is that they are triggered by scheduler instead of some other means...

Comment: Thanks @DejanLekic. I did not know that. However I can't bring the traceback back to the log file. Do I need any special configuration except a logger?

Answer (score -1):

bro just check below documentation  regards the celery signals. i thinks this will helps you.

https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/signals.html